# Custom ListView selector not showing color as expected

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView`, showing the default color of the selector as shown in the picture below.

[image: lwasis]

I would like to change color of this selector to, lets say the color teal.

ListView.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:id="@+id/lw"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

listitem_selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/teal" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/teal" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/teal" />
    <item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@color/teal" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/teal" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@color/teal" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/teal" />
    <item android:state_single="true" android:drawable="@color/teal" />
</selector>
```

As you can see, I've tried a bunch of `state_*` attributes with no success, the selected item shows as the default color. How do I change this appearance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just doing the same thing. This works for me.

I **don't** set the `@drawable` in `listview`, I have set it in format of listview i.e. in layout where you have put textViews and checkBoxes to be displayed in listview.

`list_view_format.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_view_item">

//your ckeckbox and textviews
</RelativeLayout>
```

`/res/drawable/list_view_item.xml`

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/list_item_pressed"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_activated="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/list_item_activated"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/list_item_normal" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

`/res/values/colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="list_item_normal">#96ffdcb5</color>
    <color name="list_item_activated">#ffaa66</color>
    <color name="list_item_pressed">#ffaa66</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: This works for `state_pressed`, but which state should I use when the item is selected?