# Android - Context menu no longer highlighting selected items in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an app that displays a list of articles, which when clicked on changes its background color to green.  The `ListView` is expanded by `ViewPager`.  The color change occurs so that the user knows which articles has been read.

It is also remembered, so that the next time the user loads up the same list, items that have been clicked on remains green. The code below is what I used to make this work. The problem that I am now having is that, when pressing down long enough for the context menu to appear, my articles on `ListView` no longer changes color upon selection.

Before I instigated the green background change for each item that is clicked on, selecting items in the `ListView` (context mode) used to get grayed out.  The context menu and functionality still works, but it no longer shows which items have been selected. Please can someone advise?

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int postion, long id) {
    Article a = ((toReadListAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(postion);

    // when item has been clicked on, variable is set to true.
    a.setRead(true);
    saveToReadList(toReadList);

    .....
```

Custom Adapter:

```
    // Defining custom adapter
private class toReadListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {
    public toReadListAdapter(ArrayList<Article> listToRead) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, listToRead);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_articlelistfragment, null);
        }

        Article en = getItem(position);

    .....

    /*if the article has been clicked on, then read attribute value is true and
    background is green*/
    if(en.isRead()){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C8E6C9"));

        }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundColor((Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
        }

       /* convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66BB6A"));*/

        return convertView;
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to write `xml` to change the color when item is selected. Your answer goes here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415587/custom-listview-selector-not-showing-color-as-expected/28415812#28415812

Comment: but i need the selection to be "remembered" in memory as indicated.

Comment: Does that mean you want to persist it even after you close your application?

Comment: yes. the list is like a reading list. A user might have 50 plus in that list. My problem is with the context menu selection.

Comment: You are actually setting the condition to check whether the item is selected before you set items in listView thats why your logic doesn't work. I have written my answer, I'm not sure it will work or not but try it though

Answer (score 0):

In the `onClickListener()` of listView item set

```
CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView)view;
if(item.isChecked()){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C8E6C9"));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.my problem is with the CONTEXT MENU. it no longer greys out when you select it. do you know what i can do about that?